# Creating custom commands (i.e. sending raw bytes) to Spring Data Redis?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I am modifying Redis's source code and have added several commands (say, `ZHELLOWORLD`). However, how could I call them in Spring Data Redis? Thanks!

My naive idea: We can do that using Lettuce, and we can get the underlying native library from Spring Data Redis. However, IMHO this is not that elegant, and it would be best if I could get something in the Spring Data Redis layer, not the underlying native layer.

Comment: See here https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Custom-commands,-outputs-and-command-mechanics

Comment: @123 That is what I proposed in the second paragraph :) I mean, this is not *that* elegant and I hope I can see a better solution

Comment: That's the best solution. You need to tell it how to handle your new command. That's the most abstraction you're going to get.

Comment: @123 OK... Thanks very much!

Comment: I find another way: We can just use the [lua scripting](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/reference/redis-scripting.adoc) to call whatever we want. However, the drawback is that, of course there will be an overhead for this.

Comment: That's on actual redis though.

Comment: @123 Yes but Spring provides natural APIs. I am just worried about the performance

Comment: Fair enough, never used it, but at a cursory look it does seem to be quite poor performance wise.

Comment: @123 Good suggestion. I will try to benchmark that :) I find that, in my case I actually need to use some combination of commands with atomicity, so I need to use MULTI or lua. In that case maybe it is not that slow.